# composer install complaining about php 7.2 but i'm running php 7.3

Tags: composer-php, centos7, symfony4, php-7.3

I have a symfony4 project and i'm running composer install but i'm getting the following error:

```
Problem 1
- ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 requires php ^7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 requires php ^7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 -> satisfiable by ocramius/package-versions[1.5.1].
```

however if i do a php -v

this is what i get:

```
PHP 7.3.10 (cli) (built: Sep 30 2019 22:02:36) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.10, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.10, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

can someone help me with that?

cheers,
d

Comment: what is the version number of composer ? type composer -V inside a cmd windows,

Comment: Composer version 1.9.0 2019-08-02 20:55:32

Comment: Do you have maybe a [platform](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) config in your `composer.json` file that hardcodes the PHP version to 7.2.23 ? If so, you need to remove it and run `composer update` again. Be careful though, if your prod servers are still running PHP 7.2, than this might break on your production. In that case, you need to keep the config in your composer.json file and make sure that all your dependencies support PHP 7.2.

Comment: What is the output of `/usr/bin/env php -v`?

Comment: fixed, by uninstalling XAMPP, removing composer, reinstalling everything from start... seems to be working now... not the ideal solution but i was tired of trying everything else with no luck